# CNN and batch size

Tags: conv-neural-network, batch-processing

#Hello, for a customized CNN that I train on a picture dataset with the method fit_generator , I don't #understanbd why it doesn't work with a low batch size and it works when I increase the batch _size #parameter ? Could somebody explain me what's wrong ?

```
nb_train_samples = 700
nb_validation_samples = 70
epochs = 50
batch_size = 5 ###
```

[loops of CNN don't work when the batch size is too low (ex : 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjE6Q.png)

Comment: What is the output of the `len(training_set)`?

Comment: the output len(training_set) is 22

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** In simple words, your `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` can not be more than `len(train_generator)` if it is batched already. (Assuming it is not repeated.)

---

The generator is already batched. You are trying to pass more steps than `len(training_set)` with `nb_train_samples // batch_size` which is equal to 140.

You don't need to set `steps_per_epoch` when using generators, unless you want to have less steps.

Example:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        ...
        batch_size=20)
train_generator.samples # returns 2000
```

So in this case `len(train_generator)` returns 100. If you want to use less data-points then you can specify `steps_per_epoch` like:

```
  steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // 32 <-- equals to 62
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept it with tick-mark that is below the voting buttons. If something is not clear, please let me know therefore I can edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have a last question. For fitting the CNN model , how do we define number of train sample and number of validation sample. In this personnal exercice, I have 700 train samples (2classes) et 70 validation sample. Is it recommanded to simply use  number of train sample = 700 and number of validation sample = 70 ? Thank you

Comment: If you mean steps_per_epoch and validation_steps, let `fit()` method determine them. The number of steps is calculated as follows: *total_samples // batch_size*.

Comment: ok thank you, but how do we determine total_sample figure used for : total_samples // batch_size ?

Comment: `train_generator.samples` will return total_samples.